# How to only render child component if parent prop evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have tons of conditional logic where only need to show something if the data exists. So a lot of the logic looks like this (simplified version):

```
 { 
    users
    && 
    <span>{user.length}</span>
 }
```

So I created a component that only renders the children if the prop evaluated to true, like this:

```
const If = ({truthy, children}) => (
  truthy ? <>{children}</> : null
)
```

Looks like this in practice:

```
<If truthy={users}>
  {users.length}
</If>
```

However, this does not work and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I'm getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` if users is undefined which means that the children are being evaluated first. Is that what's supposed to happen in React? Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: The children are being evaluated first indeed, they need to be because you're sending them as render parameters to the `If` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just want to add that you can use render props to solve this problem:

```
<If truthy={users}>
  {(users) => users.length}
</If>
```

and

```
const If = ({truthy, children}) => (
  truthy ? <>{children(truthy)}</> : null
)
```

But is it worth it ?

Comment: We just replaced `{users && users.length}` with `{(users) => users.length}` __AND__ added an extra component and extra API to teach our teammates :)

Comment: Yep not worth it  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the contents (`children` in this case) is evaluated anyway, so the condition is not really helpful when you want to access inner properties of objects that may be `null` / `undefined`.

I wrote a [similar library](https://github.com/sag1v/react-only-when), but it also lack this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as Sagiv explained however you can simulate it with renderProps:

```
 const If = ({truthy, children}) => (
      truthy ? children(truthy) : null
    );

 <If truthy={users}>
   {
    (truthy)=>truthy.length
   }
 </If>
```